# View элемент квадратной формы

Tags: android

У меня есть TableView. Надо, чтобы по ширине он был на весь экран, а его высота была такая же, как и ширина, т.е. мне нужен квадрат на весь экран.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе onCreate

```
   table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

// узнаем размеры экрана из класса Display
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metricsB = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(metricsB);

//устанавливаем размер
table.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metricsB.widthPixels, metricsB.widthPixels));
```